Estimating Weight of Rocks from Quarry without Weighbridge
We have this process where large rocks are broken down in crushers before clients pick them up.
However, we're having trouble accurately estimating the weights of the materials coming in from the quarry.
Our weighbridge is only suitable for smaller loads, not the large unbroken rocks.
I've been wondering if there's an AI solution or any advice you might have to improve this situation.

weigh only one wheel of the truck at a time

So count the number of trucks multiplied by the max payload derated a bit - you would never run overloaded would you?

It's not uncommon for some mines to use an excavator mounted rock breaker to break up oversized rocks prior to feeding into a crusher, or prior to loading them into trucks. The usual practice is to have a oversized yard where large rocks are placed and eventually dealt with, either on a campaign basis having a rock break continually working. It depends on the amount of oversized material produced, the capacity of the oversize yard, the availability of equipment and operators to deal with the oversized material and the urgency in processing the oversized material.

If the amount of oversized material produced by the quarry is problematic, it might be better for the quarry to use a tighter blasting pattern and reduce the distances between blast holes. This however, will increase the operating cost of the quarry, with the extra amount of drilling required and the additional amount of explosives used.
Using a mobile rock breaker is a good option if the amount of oversize is not excessive. It's also safer and operationally less disruptive than the old practice of drilling oversized rocks and using explosives to break up the rocks. Sometimes an explosive pack can be placed on the surface of the oversized rock and covered with a mudpack prior to detonation to breakup a rock. There's less fly rock when rock breakers are used.
If you need to estimate the mass of a particular rock, you can always size it up and calculate its volume. Then, using the density for that type of rock you can calculate an estimate of the rock's mass.
